# Optimising Mysql Databases

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

I am planning to research how to improve my Databases (in speed , quality,queries ,transaction , indexes ) and i would like to know what are the best books for that.
I would like the links to the books on where I could download them/buy.

I wanna find out how to improve the speed on my database engine , what mistakes should I avoid or what other secrets are there I should know about that.

Comment: Down votes and no comments for what to improve. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067) would seem to be a good match for you.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/